# 5-star rating system with four attributes

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, rating-system

I couldn't find any implementation of this one.

I need to do a rating system using Parse.com where each object have four attributes that can be ranked from 1 to 5. What I know is that I would have to have a seperate class for that. What I've made up to this point is how table's column could look like:
`objectId` - in `Parse` every object has it
`attr1` - (int) attribute no 1
`attr2` - (int) attribute no 2
`attr3`- (int) attribute no 3
`attr4`- (int) attribute no 4
`objectPointer` - a `Pointer` to rated object
 
`votesSum` - (double) sum of votes

It would work like that: each rate is added to existing rate and when someone wants to know what's the rating of specific object then sum of each attribute is divided by `votesSum`. Of course there are other problem:
- how to keep same users from rating on and on the same object? (Array maybe?)
- how to let users modify their rating (that's bigger problem)

I'm looking for really simple concept here. Maybe You have faced that problem before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both problems are solvable by including a pointer to the user on the rating object.  Multiples can be disallowed on `beforeSave`, which would try to find an existing rating with the same objectPointer and the same userPointer (the new column).

And, upon finding that existing rating, `beforeSave` could either return an error, or -- even better -- just modify that existing rating, which is how the app would allow users to modify their rating.

For a system where there are **thousands of ratings**.  It might also make sense to keep a ratings total object.

So to summarize:

```
Rating object:
    objectPointer - pointer to object being rating
    userPointer - pointer to the user doing the rating
    attr1 - (int) rating for the objects attr1
    attr2 - etc
    (no sum here)

RatingTotal object:
    objectPointer - pointer to object being rating
    ratingsCount  - (int) total rating objects that exist for this objectPointer
    totalAttr1 - (int) sum of rating objects attr1
    totalAttr2 - etc


Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Rating", function(request, response) {
    // find out if there's an existing rating object
    var query = new Parse.Query("Rating");
    query.equalTo("objectPointer", request.object.objectPointer);     
    query.equalTo("userPointer", request.object.userPointer);
    query.find().then(function(result) {
        // one exists?  just delete it, and this save will replace it
        return (result)? result.destroy() : null;
    }).then(function() {
        // update the summary object
        var query = new Parse.Query("RatingTotal");
        query.equalTo("objectPointer", request.object.objectPointer);
        return query.find();     
    }).then(function(result) {
        var RatingTotal = Parse.Object.extend("RatingTotal");
        // create one if it doesn't exist
        var ratingTotal = (result)? result : new RatingTotal();
        ratingTotal.set("ratingsCount", 1+ratingTotal.get("ratingsCount"));
        var attr1 = request.object.get("attr1");
        ratingTotal.set("totalAttr1", attr1+ratingTotal.get("totalAttr1"));
        // and so on for attrs 2, 3, etc
        return ratingTotal.save();
    }).then(function() {
        response.success();
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Notice how, if we find an existing Rating object where the same user is rating the same object, then we just delete the existing one.  Since we're doing this on a beforeSave, the new one will be saved ... effectively and *edit* of the original.

Comment: So You suggest to make new object for each rating? Won't it be much to hassle for DB?

Comment: Yes.  You've described that new object perfectly sensibly.  Just add a user pointer.  Not at all a hassle for the DB.  It's exactly what the DB is for.  A little hassle for you to make a new class, but that's exactly what programmers are for ( :-)).  Seriously, if a user rating a thing is a distinct concept in your business problem, then it should be a distinct object in your database.

Comment: Great! One more question - how to compute all the ratings of certain object? Query for all the ratings in the class and then just divide each rating by size list?

Comment: Yes.  Exactly.  But for large numbers of ratings, see edit.

Comment: There will be large numbers of them. There will be couple thousands of objects, each one having four attributes to rate and multiply that by number of users (70k - 100k eventually) :)

Comment: What I don't understand is why keep `ratingsCount` if RatingObject consists of `attributes`,`userPointer` and `ratedObjectPointer` - wouldn't be `ratingCount` done by hand?

Comment: It's not a "must" but a "should".  The reason you should is that queries of > 1K objects are slower, take multiple trips across the network, to the db, etc.  All for what might be a very common question (what's the average).  The idea of a summary object is, rather than doing all that work in a big clump each time you ask the average question, spread that work out, doing a little bit of it each time a new rating is created.

Comment: How about entirely new class for summaries? This way incrementing is done just in one place and the same would be for querying. I'm asking a lot because topic seemed to be trivial yet it's complicated :)

Comment: Yes.  I'm suggesting two new classes.  One that describes ratings (like what you had in the OP, but a separate class with a user pointer), and another that summarizes the ratings class as described in my edit.

Comment: Exquisite! One piece of this puzzle left: what about edits? When user changed his mind and would like to change his rating - seems to be more complex. `ratingCounts` remain unchanged, but `attributes` will change. What I recon I should go with: 1) find that user rating on that object in Rating class 2) make appropiate changes in RatingsSummary class. Maybe I should just drop edit functionality for now? ;)

Comment: I edited to summarize my advice, providing two objects and code that explains how to implement editing for a user's rating, and how to keep summaries up to date (including creating them initially).  All untested, off the top of my head, so don't be surprised by syntax error / dumb mistakes.  But the basic idea described is correct and commonplace.

Comment: That's terrific! Couldn't ask for more. Much appreciated - very well made :) Now I'm ready to make that. Thanks again!!! :)))